# Remove [mdb] -> [ms-access] synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-removal-request

While monitoring the [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) tag, I've encountered an unusual number of questions about Angular issues. I've tracked these questions down to the mdbootstrap library. They're using the mdb tag synonym, and thus get the [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) tag.

mdb also is the file extension for Access databases for the pre-2007 versions of Access, but these are all no longer supported and the format is outdated. Currently, there are very few questions being asked about that file format, and that's probably only going to decrease.

Please remove the synonym, to avoid these questions being tagged with the wrong tag, or consider redirecting it to [mdbootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mdbootstrap)